# Save variable from keyword to robot framework

Tags: variables, robotframework, keyword

I have an issue regarding to variables in robot framework and I did not find a similar question which fulfill my problem.

My issue:

I import my shell scripts (bash) in my Library as Keywords and run these Keywords in my Robot Framework scripts.

Next, I want to save the result-variable from my shell script after running my keyword as a proper variable in Robot.

And use it for further applications.

I found a way to set in settings the variabl:

```
***Settings***
|Variables|  script.py

***Variables***
${var}       testvariable
```

But I do not know if fulfill my problem because I use shell.

I hope my question is understandable. My main question is about how to save a variable from a other script. I hope the shell part is not confusing:)

Thank you.

Best regards
psad

Comment: Is the variable defined only in the sh script, or the py library also has it? If it's the 1st case, then you don't have access to it - it's in an external process. The library keyword should get the variable value and make it available to RF. Edit your question with samples, it's not very clear what you're dealing with right now.

Comment: You could check if `Run Process` keyword in `Process` library helps. It can return stdout to Robot and you should be able to parse your variable from there.